# UICollectionViewCell content invisible on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, swift, xcode6, uicollectionviewcell

I've got an universal iOS app which can run on iPhone or iPad.

On iPad I can't see the content of the UICollectionViewCell, but I'm able to see them if I add  a background color to them.

Here is the code : https://github.com/rvi/collectionViewTest

Screenshot on iPad :

[image: iPad]

Screenshot on iPhone :

[image: iPhone]

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was close to the one proposed by gabbler, is to select `wAny|hAny` size class on the subviews (button and switch), like this :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the delegate of the collection view to get the collectionView delegate methods called. And also add the collectionView to the view of the view controller. I can't see those things on the ViewController.swift file.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the cell in wAny|hAny size class, and you will see it on iPad. Right now the cell in size class for iPad is grayed out. Another way is to add switch and button for size class wRegular | hAny.

Comment: @Rémy Virin's answer will fix the problem,you can always start with `wAny|hAny` if your app support many device,here is the [revised version](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3oikvvkw67b57t4/CollectionViewTest1.zip?dl=0).